# .Net File IO - How to read file creation date asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, file, io, async-await

I need to determine a file's creation date over an intranet network (async).

I've figured out how to async read the file using this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/using-async-for-file-access

The typical approach for getting a creation date is to use `File` or `FileInfo` classes. But these don't seem to have direct async support. Is there an async equivalent to `File.GetCreationTime()`? Or, would it be possible to determine creation date from a `FileStream`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it have to be pure asynchrously in terms of I/O or would creating a task be okay, too? `var creationTime = await Task.Run(() => File.GetCreationTime());`

Comment: He is likely asking for an async API which was never implemented. LIkely because it was considered a fast operation anyway (compared to readigng a file which can transfer a lot of data) and thus deemed surplus or put on a very low priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *BCL* way to do this, in fact you would have to build this your self out of *win32 apis* `CreateFile` giving it the right *flags* to get the metadata using OVERLAPPED structure for Asynchronous I/O (this would make more sense if it was over a network)

The other option is to just *offload*, meaning offload this work to another thread and pretending it's true `async` (which it is not), in that case you would just use `Task.Run` for a threadpool thread.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.